# Creating a function to implement the Jacobi method

Tags: matrix

Suppose A is a 50 x 50 tridiagonal matrix with entries ai,i = 0.5 on the diagonal, ai,i-1 = ai,i+1 = 0.25 on the super diagonal and sub diagonal and zeros elsewhere. Take b to have i-th entry equal to 1/i. Starting with x0 = (1, 1, …, 1)

How would you create a Mathematica code that applies the Jacobi method to this matrix where the stop threshold is 10^-5?

Comment: I assume you mean the **Jacobi** method. What have you tried? I can at least tell you how to construct that matrix: `trid[n_] := 
 DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1/2, n]] + 
  DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1/4, n - 1], 1] + 
  DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1/4, n - 1], -1]` then use `trid[50]` and visualize with `MatrixForm`.